# Waiting for Masonry grid layout to be ready, before clicking button

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

Our app uses [Masonry grid](https://masonry.desandro.com/) layout. After page_A opens, the tiles keep moving for a second or two.

The test case is: open the page_A and click on the button which opens page_B.

While clicking the button I get either element click intercepted exception or nothing happens. Which I assume the button gets clicked but no event has fired, because it is too soon, maybe not all the functions have finished loading.

I tried explicit waits with
`ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated` and
`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` but I get results mentioned above.

How to solve this without Thread.sleep?

Preferably I would like to not use the second loading page_B (check the URL or elements on page_B) as a criteria since it is a slow loading page and it has other problems.

Is there a way to know if the click was "successful"? Like if it has fired an onClick action, or started a function (I am not very good at JS).

Answer (score 0):

Masonry has an [event system](https://masonry.desandro.com/events.html#vanilla-js-event-binding). You could bind an `layoutComplete` event to set a global variable to true and poll that with the [WebDriver JavaScriptExecuter](https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html).

This [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720325/selenium-webdriver-wait-for-complex-page-with-javascript-to-load) also explains how to use the `JQuery.active` state to monitor if the page is still working on rendering. Masonry seems to be often used with jQuery, so maybe that is a possible solution.

Waiting for a state with the JavaScriptExecuter is a bit complex. As an alternative in the past I have created a waitMethod that tries to click on an element, which waits for an expected new element for some milliseconds, if the new element does not show, try and click again.

```
waitForElementToShowAfterClick(By elementToClick, By elementToWaitFor, milliSecondsToWait = 1000, timesToRetry = 3) {
   // implementation
   return elementToWaitFor
}
```